# Chrome translation often crashes input fields

Tags: spring, google-chrome, input, vaadin, translation

While developing a Chrome translation detection I came across a weird Chrome behaviour:

When a page is translated by google, quite often it is not possible to type text into input fields on the translated page. With normal text fields, text may be shown in reverse order. With password fields, no typed chars are shown (so the * representing a char). When I switch back to the original language, all of a sudden the text is shown, so Chrome seems to save it somewhere but just does not display it.

Sometimes the language is not detected correct, so I use the "This page is not in ..." functionality of Chrome to set it to the correct value. This seemed to be the reason for this strange behaviour in the first place. But after quite a few tests, it may not be the problem. In both cases (with setting the correct language or not) it works sometimes, but ore often it does not. I could not find a pattern so far.

This happens on other computers of other people as well, so it does not seem to be a problem with my computer.

It is a page developed with Vaadin and Spring and the page this came up was the login page. I use the LoginForm functionality of Vaadin, so maybe that's a possible reason for this behaviours. I tested the translation on other pages with input fields as well, and there it seems to work. But I'm not sure if this isn't just Murphys law.

Anyone any idea about this?